# Why is only the first shown window focusable

Tags: winforms, focus

Imagine the code below. Only the first window appears on the top, all of subsequent windows won't nor can they be programatically focused for some reason (they appear in the background). Any idea how to workaround this? BTW, static methods/properties are not allowed nor is any global property.

```
[STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(CreateForm);
        t1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t1.Start();
        t1.Join();

        t1 = new Thread(CreateForm);
        t1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t1.Start();
        t1.Join();
    }

    private static void CreateForm()
    {
        using (Form f = new Form())
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer
            {
                Enabled = true,
                Interval = 2000
            };
            t.Tick += (s, e) => { f.Close(); t.Enabled = false; };

            f.TopMost = true;
            Application.Run(f);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How can you have two items as 'TopMost'?

Imagine a queue at the box office. If you are the first person at the queue, no one else can take the first spot. If someone takes the first spot, you automatically lose your first spot.

Could you tell us what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Due to Join() the windows are created and shown in the sequence, not at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Hans Passant [solved the problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/ac30b1cd-828f-4738-b3f7-1418ef3c65f1): just use SetForegroundWindow() (P/Invoke). Shees, I should have though of that :-)